# Peak detector working in two regimes

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplitude

I measured the input and output of a peak detector and a very interesting pattern occured...

[image: Amplitude of input and output voltage on peak detector]

I expected a single straight line but got two. Why is that so? Is it due to something else in the scheme or is just a quirk of the opamp?

The input I'm referring to is pin 5 on IC1B and the output is measured right after diode D1.

[image: Peak detector IC1B/opamp LT1807]

The pulses look like this where Ch1 is the input and Ch2 the output

[image: Pulses as seen on an oscilloscope]

The whole circuit diagram just in case...

[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: Why not try figuring this out by using a simulator.

Comment: Can we assume that the scope traces are the signals at "SiPM amplified" and "PeakDetOut" on the diagram? It seems clear that the circuit is nowhere near fast enough to capture a 400 ns pulse -- probing pin 7 of the opamp would help confirm this. It's a fast opamp (125 V/µs slew rate), but putting a 20 nF cap on its output reduces that to about 4 V/µs because of its output current limit.

Comment: 20nf is a lot of capacitance to charge in a short time. Hard to tell from that photo, but I wonder if the opamp is hitting its current limit during that pulse? Try a smaller capacitance if you are able.

Comment: You've heavy loaded yout opamp by 20nF capacity (you can see slow upramp on oscilloscope trace). And probably event without it your opamp will have some troubles  to work pricesely due "recovery" time. There are no informations about used diodes. From scope trace it looks like you are inputting negative voltage on single supply opamp. Where do you get that graph ? And what exactly is "output" voltage (output voltage changes over time while C8 discharging !). If you want to build fast peak detector, you have to completly rework your design.

Comment: Where did you get this circuit? I'm trying to figure out the purpose of R8. In conjunction with R9, it's forcing the peak detector to have a gain of 2. This means that the output of the opamp is sitting at either a diode drop below V_in, or a diode drop above 2×V_in, which means a much larger slew is required each time a pulse occurs, exacerbating your problem. Also, what about R7? It looks like a useless load on the output of the previous stage. In addition, this opamp has a relatively high input bias current, and you've made no effort to balance that out.

Comment: You might want to try the circuits shown in figures 3 or 5 [here](https://sound-au.com/appnotes/an014.htm).

Comment: I'll do a simulation. What is the pulse repetition rate? Do all the pulses look like the one on the scope? Do you want it to settle on the first pulse, or is it okay if it takes several pulses to capture the peak, and if so, how many?

Comment: @bobflux The pulses come at a frequency of 0.5Hz and they all have the same shape. My scope was working in a way that it caught the first pulse that came up (if that's what you mean by settling). Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Dave Tweed I largely copied the circuit from here: https://github.com/spenceraxani/CosmicWatch-Desktop-Muon-Detector-v2/blob/master/PCB_Files/circuit.pdf I'll try it with a smaller capacitance and without the R7 once I get my hands on a scope again. But how could I reduce the bias current- by adding a resistor? Isn't that what the R7 is for?

Comment: @DaveTweed it was quite a lot of detective work, see my answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

> The pulses come at a frequency of 0.5Hz and they all have the same shape

OK. C8-R9 has a time constant of 2ms, C8-R10 has a time constant of 500µs, there is 2000ms between two pulses, so C8 has way more than enough time to completely discharge between two peaks.

Peak detectors are really hard, especially on fast signals. Problems are:

- The opamp has to charge the cap to the peak value in a very short amount of time.

In this case you have a rise time of about 100ns for 4V so 40V/µs. To follow that slew rate the 20nF cap has to take a charge current of...

\$ i=C dv/dt = 0.8A \$

That's not gonna happen, even if we mercifully add 100ns extra since the input signal is a bit rounded on top. So the opamp dumps as much current as it can into  the cap, which raises output voltage by a blip, and then the signal you want to detect is gone and the opamp calls it a day.

- So the cap has to be tiny

Using a much smaller cap (like 2nF) would still require the opamp to dump 80mA, it has a max current of 85mA, so maybe.

- So the tiny cap won't hold the peak value for long

Of course a 2nF cap will discharge very quickly through R9, so you have to get rid of R9. But the opamp still needs to sense the cap voltage. Usually these peak detector circuits use another opamp as follower, but I'm not sure it's wise to insert an opamp in the feedback loop of a 325MHz opamp whose output is already loaded with a cap and thus probably running at dangerously low phase margin.

That's why I was asking about the repetition rate.

If you had lots of peaks, with a repetition rate of say 10-100kHz then it would be okay if the opamp couldn't acquire the peak completely but instead just bumped voltage on the cap in the right direction. It would get to the peak value eventually after enough repetitions. But at 0.5Hz repetition, since your cap has to be tiny to charge fast enough, there's no way to keep a voltage on it for two seconds. Even the tiniest bit of leakage will ruin it.

So you can't rely on repetition, you have to grab the peak value on the first try.

However, I don't think the circuit is supposed to measure the amplitude of the peak, but only to detect that a peak occurs. I wrote the above thinking the circuit was a nonfunctional peak amplitude detector, but that's not what it actually is.

Looking at the [original schematics](https://github.com/spenceraxani/CosmicWatch-Desktop-Muon-Detector-v2/blob/master/PCB_Files/circuit.pdf) the output of the opamp is called "PEAK_SIGN" and capacitively coupled into a microcontroller pin. Due to the cap coupling, no DC will pass through, so the MCU wouldn't be able to acquire the voltage at the output of the opamp anyway.

So I guess the first thing to do is figure out what the circuit is supposed to do.

The "[Physics Paper](https://github.com/spenceraxani/CosmicWatch-Desktop-Muon-Detector-v2/blob/master/PCB_Files/callibration.pdf)" says:

> The produced current is sent through a custom designed printed circuit board (PCB), which amplifies and shapes the signal such that it is suitable to be measured by an inexpensive micro614 controller (in our case, an Arduino Nano [54]). The Arduino Nano measures the event time stamp and peak value on the analog-to-digital converter (ADC). The measured peak ADC value can then be converted back into a SiPM peak voltage, which is proportional to the number of
> photons incident on the SiPM.

hmm... There's a pdf called "callibration" with this:

[image]

So the thing seems to be supposed to output the log of the peak amplitude... the pdf says to look into "instructions.pdf"...

> To determine the correlation between a measured ADC value from the peak detector circuit and the actual SiPM pulse amplitude, we begin with taking a screenshot of the SiPM output waveform, digitize it on a computer, and then program it into an arbitrary waveform generator. The waveform generator allows us to scale the voltage and inject it into the circuit through the BNC connection (without the SiPM PCB connected). The plot below shows the relationship between the amplitude of the injected pulse and the measured ADC value. In this image, at
> each point, we inject 200 pulses then calculate the standard deviation of the measured ADC values. We then fit the distribution according to a high-order polynomial. The result of the fit and the data is shown in Fig. 10. We use these results in the function “Calibration fit” in the Arduino code.

Aha!

Summary:

The circuit does "something" to the signal, which doesn't seem to work that well.

They "fix" it in software.

Done!

In other words, academics.

[image]

If the input pulse is high enough, the opamp enters current limit. So the output voltage depends on the length of the pulse and the opamp current limit, which is not an accurate specification.

[image]

At low amplitude, the 100k resistors are way too high to get fast response, so it outputs "something" that has a relationship with the input voltage, but it sure isn't the peak value...

Since the sensor outputs a current pulse and the purpose of this is to detect the amplitude of this pulse, I wonder why they're not simply using the current pulse to charge a small capacitor, then sampling voltage on it and resetting it.

Comment: Thanks for tracking all of that down! The original question really made no sense without all of that context.

Comment: I did scratch my head for a while! It really is a weird schematic...

Answer (score 0):

Use fast comparator instead opamp (it has better "recovery time"), fast diode with low capacity, smallest possible output capacitor, trigger ADC coversion by input pulse (delays between pulse capture and ADC leads to discharge output capacitor). In that configuration i was able to capture pulses with rise time in range of tens of nanoseconds with "uncertainty" in apmlitude about 2-3%. If i remember correctly i was using TLV360x comparator, diode BAT54 (?) and output capacitor dont remember (i've changed its value multiple times to find best results ... about 100pF ?)

*"Red" trace is input, "Yellow" trace is output of peak detector* (ignore comments in oscillographs - there was for internal use not for publication)

[image: sine pulse test1]
[image: sine pulse test2]
[image: square pulse 1][image: square pulse 2]